# How to know if the user has set a lock pattern?

Tags: android, permissions, locking, design-patterns

Is there a way to know if the user has set a lock pattern?
I checked the LockPatternUtils.java in com/android/internal/widget and find a function:

```
/**
 * Check to see if the user has stored a lock pattern.
 * @return Whether a saved pattern exists.
 */
public boolean savedPasswordExists() {
   return nonEmptyFileExists(sLockPasswordFilename);
}
```

the variable sLockPasswordFilename is set as

```
android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/system/password.key";
```

It need system permission to run, so I need to add ShareUserId in manifest and modify Android.mk, then compile using mm command. But I didn't install a virtual machine in my computer now, so I want to ask anybody done something like this, it's right? Or is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, just simply use an int variable

```
int hasPattern = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
```

the result 0 means has No pattern, 1 means has pattern.

found resolution at http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/source/browse/wiki/Patterntoggle.wiki?r=278#

Thanks all the same